# Laravel Eloquent user follow post relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tables:

**users**

```
id
```

**follows**

```
id
user_id
follow_id
```

**posts**

```
id
user_id
```

I want to get user followed user's post.
How do I set the relationship and get 
`user->follow->post`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a user can have more than one follower, and a user can follow more than one user. You need an Many To Many Relationship with the same model.

Here is:

```
<?php 

class User extends Eloquent {

        ...

        public function followers()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'follows', 'user_id', 'follow_id');
        }

        public function follows()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'follows', 'follow_id', 'user_id');
        }

}
```

Below is how you can view the users

```
$user = User::find(1);

echo $user->follows()->first()->name;
echo $user->followers()->first()->name;

// or

foreach ($user->followers as $follower)
        echo $follower->name . '<br>';
```

and etc

Comment: hi.thanks for the reply.
and how it relate to post.
if i want to retrieve the person i followed's post?

Comment: The same way, you can chain methods to continue like:

    $user->follows()->first()->posts()->first()->title;

or

    foreach ($user->follows()->first()->posts as $post)
        echo $post->title;

Comment: The posts will currently be sorted by user id. Is there a way of displaying posts according to the most recent entires?